# Countable disjoint union of non-measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can a countable union of non-measurable sets of reals be measurable?
For instance, can we partition $\mathbb{C}$ into countably many disjoint non-measurable sets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Just take any non-measurable set and its complement. For example, let $V$ be a [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set), which is known to be non-measurable. We have
$$
\mathbb R = V \cup V^\complement.
$$

Comment: Ah yes, silly me!

Comment: Isn't the mesure of $V^C = \infty$? Considering that Vitali set is constructed in an interval. Do you first fill the space with copies of Vitali set?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė No. If $V^\complement$ were measurable, its complement $V$ would be measurable too.

Comment: @AymanHourieh, clearly, $\{x>2\} \subset V^\complement$ and $m (\{x>2\}) = \infty$. Is there some contradiction in saying that $\infty = m (\{x>2\}) \leq m(V^\complement) = \infty$?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė When do you say a set is Lebesgue measurable? This needs to be based on a $\sigma$-algebra. If you say $m(V^\complement) = \infty$, this implies that $V^\complement$ and hence $V$ are measurable. Contradiction.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/26676/4583). We can use your reasoning to assign an *inner* measure to $V^\complement$, but not a measure!

Comment: @AymanHourieh, $m_{inner}(V^\complement) = m_{outer}(V^\complement) = \infty$. Doesn't this imply $m(V^\complement) = \infty$?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė This construction only works for *bounded* sets. For unbounded sets, one considers the intersection with bounded intervals. This is where your equality fails for $V^\complement$. Have a look [here](http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/talks/Measure-Theory.pdf).

Comment: @AymanHourieh, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can clearly say that in generally, countable union of non measurable sets is not non measurable. We know that union of every Vitali sets defined on [0,1] closed intervals is [0,1] and rational numbers are countablr so that we can choose some vitali sets countably which union is [0,1]