# What can you say about union of two non measurable set. They are measurable or not?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

What can you say about union of two non measurable set. They are measurable or not? Is it necessarily true?Thinking about α-cantor set I wonder if the complement of a non measurable set is a non measurable set that does the job.

Comment: This is same question of mine.But someguys put an hold on that question.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549987/countable-disjoint-union-of-non-measurable-sets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you believe that a non-measurable subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ exists then $A':=[0,1]\setminus A$ will be nonmeasurable as well, but the union $A\cup A'=[0,1]$ is measurable.

Comment: Such non-measurable subset $A$ of $[0, 1]$always exists due to Vitali's theorem.